# Question on probability and approximation

Tags: statistics, approximation, estimation

Okay I think you are all familiar to YouTube videos and some facts are:

1. to comment, like and dislike on a video you need a Google account.
2. when someone views the video the view count of the video increases by one regardless of if the viewer has a Google account or not.

Okay, having said the above I’m wondering, how useful is the data we get via the like/dislike bar? I mean, if for e.g. you've got a video with 1 million views and the like/dislike value is 4000 to 250. Can one use that data to:

1. say what would have been the trend of these 1 million people if all of them could had a Google account or should have had a 3rd data like the number of abstention value (i.e. not everyone who had the chance to interact necessarily did interact) for the like/dislike bar to be useful.
2. have an idea of what those who commented felt (i.e. if their comments were +ve or -ve) without having to have to go through each one of their comments.

Comment: I would say either of those inferences would be extremely dicey due to selection biases. That is, the set of voters is unlikely to be particularly representative of the set of viewers.

Comment: @Shane I'm not sure i understand. Can you explain some more please. Between my little theory about it was like the voters would be my sample and the viewers my population and with some assuption we would roughly extend things.

Comment: I included my thoughts as a comment because I think there are others who can provide better answers than I can. My thinking is that you could argue that the set of voters is a representative sample of the set of viewers if the voters were randomly drawn from the set of viewers, but that isn't the case. Instead, the voters chose to express their opinion in a vote whereas the non-voters chose not to. If that choice is correlated with their opinion on the video (and it seems likely it would be), then the set of voters is not representative of the set of viewers.

Comment: I would probably, as a first approximation, model non-voters as viewers who had neither positive nor negative opinion on the video itself. But even that is problematic since some may have had a strong opinion but not an account, and therefore they couldn't vote. Others may have had a strong opinion but still not voted, just because there is little incentive to do so. Therefore, I think any inference you do on the set of viewers using the set of voters as a sample will be deeply problematic.

Comment: @Shane I probably should have said thanks on my first reply xD so I apologize for that and don't worry your contribution is very much appreciated. 
Ok on topic now. I agree with what you said about the randomness of the sample and if I understood you well, your idea is that the voters are not representative of the viewers because some of the voters can abstain and as it stands we have only data of those who voted be it +ve and -ve and by using that data to approximate on our population i.e. the viewers we will force everyone to be in either for or against the video.

Comment: @Shane But if we do that, roughly speaking how far do you think we'll be off of the true answer?

Comment: No problem, happy to help. In terms of how far off, let me answer your question with a question. What exactly are you trying to estimate? And how important is accuracy? If you're trying to make a rough argument that viewers like cat videos more than dog videos for an undergraduate stats class, I think it's basically fine to do what you propose. If you're trying to argue a more important point and in a setting where rigor is more important (i.e. something you would submit to an academic journal), I don't think they would let you get away with ignoring the selection bias.

Comment: @Shane Thxs for the input pretty much my thoughts but hearing someone else say it makes me feel better xD.

Comment: Good to hear. If you're satisfied with that as an answer, let me know and I'll format the comments above into an answer that you can accept so the question closes (just makes for a healthier forum). Otherwise, we can leave it unanswered in the hope that somebody else provides a more comprehensive answer. Up to you.

Comment: @Shane Pls do, I'm fine with it ;).

Answer (score 1):

I would say either of those inferences would be extremely dicey due to selection biases. That is, the set of voters is unlikely to be particularly representative of the set of viewers.

My thinking is that you could argue that the set of voters is a representative sample of the set of viewers if the voters were randomly drawn from the set of viewers, but that isn't the case. Instead, the voters chose to express their opinion in a vote whereas the non-voters chose not to. If that choice is correlated with their opinion on the video (and it seems likely it would be), then the set of voters is not representative of the set of viewers.

I would probably, as a first approximation, model non-voters as viewers who had neither positive nor negative opinion on the video itself. But even that is problematic since some may have had a strong opinion but not an account, and therefore they couldn't vote. Others may have had a strong opinion but still not voted, just because there is little incentive to do so. Therefore, I think any inference you do on the set of viewers using the set of voters as a sample will be deeply problematic.

In terms of how far off you would be, let me answer your question with a question. What exactly are you trying to estimate? And how important is accuracy? If you're trying to make a rough argument that viewers like cat videos more than dog videos for an undergraduate stats class, I think it's basically fine to do what you propose. If you're trying to argue a more important point and in a setting where rigor is more important (i.e. something you would submit to an academic journal), I don't think they would let you get away with ignoring the selection bias.